# The ring $C$ has a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2 \times \dots \mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: ring-theory

Let be $C$ a commutative ring such that $1+1=0$ and $0\neq 1$. I want to prove:

> There exist rings $C_i$ such that  $C\cong C_1\times \cdots\times C_n$ if and only if $C$ has a sub-ring isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2^n$

**Some ideas:**

- If two rings are isomorphic then has the same characteristic.
- If a Ring has characteristic $n$ then it has a sub-ring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n.$
- A boolean ring is generated by copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2.$

Can help me how order these ideas?

Comment: What are all the $C_i$ supposed to be?

Comment: Your $\iff$ statement has no conditions on the left side. What is the question?

Comment: $C_i$ are rings

Comment: But what about them?  $C=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is a commutative ring (that is a direct product) with no subrings iso to $\mathbb{F}_2$ or direct copies thereof.  What's the question?

Comment: The idempontents aren’t a subring. But the ideals generated by individual idempotents is a subring.

Comment: I want to prove: There exist $C_i$ such that $C$ is isomorphic to a direct produc of $C_i$  if only if $C$ has a subring isomorphic to a direct product of copies of $\mathbb{F}_2$

Comment: Ok, I'm no sure if idempotents are a subring.

Comment: Your title is incomplete. That is a risk of trying to put the whole question in the title. Ask the question in the body of the question, even when it fits in the title. The title has another purpose - to let readers decide quickly if they can help. The body should have the complete details.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I am a beginner.

Comment: So, the question is: If $C$ is a commutative ring with  $1+1=0$ then $C$ is the direct product of $n$ rings if and only if $C$ has a subring isomorphic to  $\mathbb F_2^n.$

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks!

Comment: Ahhhhh, so so much better.

Answer (score 1):

If $e_1,\dots,e_n$ are the standard idempotents of $\mathbb F_2^n,$ then $e_i\neq 0,1$ are idempotents in $C,$ and $e_ie_j=0$ when $i\neq j.$ Let $e_{n+1}=1-(e_1+\cdots+e_n).$

Show $e_{n+1}$ is an idempotent and $e_ie_{n+1}=0$ for $i<n+1,$ and $1=e_1+\cdots+e_{n+1}.$

Then let $C_i=e_iC.$ Show the $C_i$ are rings. Show $C\cong C_1\times \cdots\times C_{n+1}.$ Then $$C\cong C_1\times \cdots\times C_{n-1}\times\left(C_{n}\times C_{n+1}\right)$$

Note, while it is possible that $e_{n+1}$ might be $0,$ the ring $C_n\times C_{n+1}$ is not a zero ring.

Comment: Grateful for your proof's sketch.